# I have some issue about this example in c# local variables

Tags: c#

here I understand the meaning of local vaiables.
but what does that my SecondVar do?
Doesn't method2 give myValue to my SecondVar?

These code meant to set "something" as myVar to myValue in method2, so what is the function of mySecondVar here?

```
private void method1()
{
    // This is a local variable called myVar
    string myVar = "something";

    string mySecondVar = method2(myVar);
}

private string method2(string myValue)
{
    // This method has received myVar from method1 as "myValue"
    return myValue;
}
```

Comment: Probably there so you can see that `myVar == mySecondVar` (as a demo showing how to return a value through a function).

Comment: Is this all the code that you have?  Here you just have two unused local variable that also happen to have the same reference to a single string.  It doesn't really *do* anything if this is all there is to it.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote any helpful answers and accept the answer that helped solve your question, method2 looks like an example method to show someone how methods work, it just returns the string value passed to it right back to the string variable mySecondVar

Answer (score 1):

Both are local variables. And both will have the same values according to your code. `mySecondVar` gets the value of `myVar` indirectly.

Answer (score 1):

```
string mySecondVar = method2(myVar);
```

This line of code calls method2, passing myVar, and assigns the return value of the method call to mySecondVar. Normally, method2 would actually do something with the value before returning it. In this example it does nothing, so you end up with "something" assigned to mySecondVar.

Answer (score 0):

Both are local variables as they are declared in the **same scope**.

```
string myVar = "something";
```

Here, you are directly initializing myVar to some value.

```
string mySecondVar = method2(myVar);
```

Here, you are assinging the value returned by `method2()` to `mySecondVar`. `method2()` returns the value of `myVar` without any operation on it, so `mySecondVar` also gets initialized to the same value as `myVar`.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that method2 is doing is taking in the string value "something", in your case, and returning that same value "something" back to mysecondvar. It's strictly taking in a string and returning that same string.

Answer (score 0):

This is just to illustrate that a function will return a value of the type it is supposed to return. 
In this case the function method2 is of a string type and it returns the value it receives as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, they are both local variables and this example illustrates how methods get and return values.

The most interesting part of what's going on here is that strings in C# are not primitives, so the local variable you declare is actually a reference to an object, rather than the object data itself.  So in this code, you have essentially set up two local variables to reference the same object, rather than two distinct copies of the same object.

Local variables are allocated in the stack frame for this method (hence, why they are "local" to this method), whereas objects are generally allocated on the heap.

This doesn't really matter much in this example, because strings are **immutable**, so neither of these references could edit the object without the other reference knowing.  But it's still nice to think about!